# Avoid JPanel from getting over another

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

I'm trying to load JPanels inside another but I can see only one, the others get hidden behind it.
This is my code:

```
    pnlResultados.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    for (int i = 0; i < cantResultados; i++) {
        pResultado pr = new pResultado(modelo, resultados.get(i), padre, this);
        System.out.println("panel");
        pnlResultados.add(pr);
        pr.setVisible(true);
    }
    pnlResultados.setVisible(true);
    pnlResultados.revalidate();
    pnlResultados.repaint();
```

I have used `System.out.printl` to see how many pannels I'm creating and inserting and that seems alright. The problem is that they all get alocated in the same place, one over the other.
How can I avoid this behaviour?
Thank you

Comment: See also [Why does the first panel added to a frame disappear?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30361149/418556)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't specify a constraint when adding a component to the BorderLayout, all components go to the CENTER. However, only the last component added will be visible.

The solution is to use a different layout manager.

Since you are adding components in a loop, I would suggest you might want to look at a `GridLayout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

You can always nest panels with different layout manager to achieve your desired layout.