# Only first object visible on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, object, jframe

I'm not sure how to title this question so if you have a better one, please let me know.

My question is about Objects on JFrames. I'm given a class that is called `ThreeButtonFrame` and looks like this:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/** ThreeButtons and ThreeButtonFrame supplier Classes
 * Author: David D. Riley
 * Date: April, 2004
 *
 *  ThreeButtons supports button events for the ThreeButtonFrame class.
 *  This class is designed to be inherited and its methods overridden.
 */
public abstract class ThreeButtons  {  

    /** The method below is an event handler for button clicks on
     *  the LEFT button of an object of type A3ButtonWindow 
     */
    public abstract void leftAction();

    /** The method below is an event handler for button clicks on
     *  the MID button of an object of type A3ButtonWindow 
     */
    public abstract void midAction();

    /** The method below is an event handler for button clicks on
     *  the RIGHT button of an object of type A3ButtonWindow 
     */
    public abstract void rightAction();

    /** The class below provides a JFrame that includes three JButtons (left, mid and right).
     *  The event handling of these three buttons will be performed by the leftAction
     *  midAction and rightAction methods of the subclass of ThreeButtons. 
     */
    protected class ThreeButtonFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
        private JButton leftButton, midButton, rightButton;

        public ThreeButtonFrame(String s) {
            super(s);
            setBounds(20, 20, 600, 500);
            setVisible(true);
            Container pane = getContentPane();
            pane.setLayout(null);
            leftButton = new JButton("LEFT");
            leftButton.setBounds(100, 430, 100, 30);
            leftButton.addActionListener(this);
            pane.add(leftButton, 0);
            midButton = new JButton("MID");
            midButton.setBounds(250, 430, 100, 30);
            midButton.setText("MID");
            midButton.addActionListener(this);
            pane.add(midButton, 0);
            rightButton = new JButton("RIGHT");
            rightButton.setBounds(400, 430, 100, 30);
            rightButton.addActionListener(this);
            pane.add(rightButton, 0);
            pane.repaint();
        }

        public void setBackground(Color c) {
            super.getContentPane().setBackground(c);
        }

        /** Event Handler
         *  This method is called whenever any of the three
         *  buttons is clicked   
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
            if (e.getSource() == leftButton)
                leftAction();
            else if (e.getSource() == midButton)
                midAction();
            else if (e.getSource() == rightButton)
                rightAction();      
        }

    }

}
```

**I'm then given the `Rectangle` class:**

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

/** Rectangle Supplier Class 
 * Author: David D. Riley
 * Date: April, 2004
 */
public class Rectangle extends JComponent  {

    /** post:   getX() == x  and  getY() == y
     *          and  getWidth() == w  and getHeight() == h
     *          and  getBackground() == Color.black
     */
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h)  {
        super();
        setBounds(x, y, w, h);
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    /** post:   this method draws a filled Rectangle
     *          and  the upper left corner is (getX(), getY()) 
     *          and  the rectangle's dimensions are getWidth() and getHeight()
     *          and  the rectangle's color is getBackground()
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g)  {
       // ((Graphics2D)g).setClip( new Ellipse2D.Double(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight()) );
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
        paintChildren(g);
   }

}
```

I then create a class called `Analyzer` that extends the `Rectangle` class and inside this class I initialize 2 `JLabel`'s, a `JTextField`.

`Analyzer`:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Sully on 4/5/16.
 */
public class Analyzer extends Rectangle {

    private JLabel topLabel;
    private JLabel resultLabel;
    private JTextField text;

    public Analyzer(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super(x, y, w, h);
        topLabel = new JLabel("Enter your sentence below: ");
        topLabel.setBounds(getX(), getY() - 25, 225, 30);
        topLabel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        text = new JTextField("BLAHBLAH");
        text.setBounds(topLabel.getX() + 2, topLabel.getY() + 30, 350, 20);
        text.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        resultLabel = new JLabel("Results: ");
        resultLabel.setBounds(text.getX() - 5, text.getY() + 20, 150, 30);
        resultLabel.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        setBackground(Color.white);


        add(topLabel);
        add(text);
        add(resultLabel);
        repaint();


    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // ((Graphics2D)g).setClip( new Ellipse2D.Double(getX(), getY(),                    getWidth(), getHeight()) );
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        paintChildren(g);
    }

}
```

In a driver class where I initialize a `ThreeButtonFrame` object and add Analyzer objects to the frame, although when I make 3 separate objects in my driver class like so:

```
Analyzer a1 = new Analyzer(win.getX() + 1, win.getY() + 10, 450, 100);
    Analyzer a2 = new Analyzer(a1.getX() + 25, a1.getY() + (30 + a1.getHeight()), 450, 100);
    Analyzer a3 = new Analyzer(a2.getX() + 25, a2.getY() + (30 + a2.getHeight()), 450, 100);
win.add(a1, 0);        
win.add(a2, 0);
    win.add(a3, 0);


    win.repaint();
```

Only the first call (a1) is visible. The remaining 2 white boxes are added but without the elements. Why is this?

I tried changing the variables in the `Analyzer` class to instance variables inside the constructor method.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the first panel added to a frame disappear?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30361149/418556)

Comment: It's a little hard to tell, but you "seem" to be trying to offset the location of your components across containers, which really isn't what the container API is designed for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a significant misunderstanding in how container layout management works.  Child components are automatically offset by the containers x/y position, this makes the child component's position contextual to the parent container, meaning that the top/left position is always 0x0 within any given container

For example, if I change...

```
topLabel.setBounds(getX(), getY() - 25, 225, 30);
```

to

```
topLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 225, 30);
```

It will generate...

[image: Screen]

Having said that, I would STRONGLY discourage you from doing this and start using appropriate layout managers